# Cannot submit form on CiviCRM 4.7.7, might be related to CRM-18510?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, profile

With CiviCRM 4.7.7 on Drupal 6, we are seeing crashes such as:

```
    May 18 11:16:34  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => One of parameters  (value: `1-street_address`) is not of the type MysqlColumnName
    [code] =>
)


May 18 11:16:34  [info] $backTrace = #0 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(371): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(424): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("One of parameters  (value: `1-street_address`) is not of the type MysqlColumn...")
#2 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Sort.php(124): CRM_Utils_Type::validate("`1-street_address`", "MysqlColumnName")
#3 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(222): CRM_Utils_Sort->__construct((Array:7), NULL)
#4 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Listings.php(394): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->__construct(Object(CRM_Profile_Selector_Listings), NULL, NULL, 4, Object(CRM_Profile$
#5 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Profile/Page/Router.php(124): CRM_Profile_Page_Listings->run()
#6 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Profile_Page_Router->run((Array:2), NULL)
#7 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#8 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#9 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(345): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#10 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("profile")
#11 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/includes/menu.inc(350): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:1))
#12 /srv/www/sites/orgdomainname.org/www/index.php(17): menu_execute_active_handler()
#13 {main}
```

This looks similar to what is reported here:

CRM-18510 "Getting 'One of parameters (value: `Home-street_address`) is not of the type MysqlColumnName' error when Contact Search is used."

However since we are seeing the error when trying to submit forms (CiviMember + CiviContribute + Profile) rather than to search, I am not sure if what is reported with CRM-18510 is actually the same as what we are seeing.

If it is probably the same, please point me to what diff/patch I should test applying to our CiviCRM 4.7.7 on D6 configuration.

I am thankful,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks likely to be the same underlying problem as the issue described in [CRM-18510](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18510). There's a fix referenced there: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8317 . If you test this out, do report your findings here and on CRM-18510 . Hope it works for you.

Regards,

Dave

Comment: Is there some way to download from github as a patch file that may be applied with patch? I found a YouTube video showing such, however the example was showing how to convert a single commit to a patch by simply adding ".patch" to the URL. This CRM-18510 there are five commits for. What is on the "Files Changed" tab looks complete, however it will not apply as a patch.

Comment: Try https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/8317.patch This includes changes to unit tests under the civicrm/tests/ directory, which only exists in development installations, so you may want to remove those parts from the patch before applying.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. I just applied that Diff to our test site and ran a test new member join. I got back from CiviCRM: 
Your transaction has been processed successfully. Please print this page for your records.
An email receipt has also been sent to test2@orgdomainname.org
With that success I applied the patch to Prod as well. Now the wait to see who fills out a CiviCRM form next, and if it too successfully processes. "The suspense is terrible, I hope it will last." Willy Wonka ;-)

Comment: I just received confirmation that transactions now successfully are processing in Prod. I will try to update the CRM-18510 case explaining your patch URL works in our site's case. Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Glad to have helped. Well done for updating the JIRA issue. Thanks for accepting the answer. If you feel it's useful, it's usual to up-vote too - a quirk of Stack Exchange, see [Accepting answer without upvoting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting)

Comment: Upvoted as well. Thanks for pointing that step out.